# Bazel to read spring boot application.properties configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bazel, application.properties

I have a very simple Spring Boot application that uses Maven and I'm trying to migrate it to use Bazel.
I'm following the "[Migrating from Maven to Bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/migrate-maven.html)" tutorial and I've now the Spring Boot application running using Bazel.

The problem is that my **application.properties** (created in "src/main/resources") file is not being loaded by Spring, where I have setted up e.g. the port where my application runs.

My BUILD file is the following:

```
 java_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    #visibility = ["//src/test:__subpackages__"],
    deps = [
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_autoconfigure",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_web",
    ],
)
java_binary(
    name = "app",
    main_class = "com.myapp.MyApplication",
    runtime_deps = [
        ":lib",
    ],
)
```

How can I achieve to load my application.properties file using Bazel?

Comment: How are you running the app? Files in `src/main/resources` should be copied by the build system into a place that ends up on the classpath of the JVM that's running the application.

Comment: Try using [`java_library.resources`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_library.resources) to include `application.properties`?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I am running the application this way: "bazel run //src/main/java/com/myapp:app".

Comment: I was able to make it work using "java_library.resources". I'm struggling with doing simple things with Bazel. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include data files like `applications.properties` in your JAR, use the `resources` attribute on the `java_library` or `java_binary` rule.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_library.resources

Here's [an example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/8753302a59003242e61896d575df04912ec458f3/examples/java-native/src/main/java/com/example/myproject/BUILD#L25-L29) on its usage.